# MySQL select rows where the JSON array column is a subset of another array

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

Hy, I have a table of `machines` with a JSON array column called `cells`. Some example data:

```
machine_id  | cells
-----------------------------------------
1           | ['TE001', 'GM0002']
2           | ['TE001', 'TK123', 'AW123']
3           | ['TK123', 'GS123']
```

I also have an array of cells that are compatible to a specific machine version, e.g.

```
('TE001', 'GM0002', 'TK123', 'GS123', 'LL321')
```

I need a query to extract all the machines whose `cells` are ALL contained into my machine version cells.

```
machine_id  | shouldSelect | explaination
------------------------------------
1           | true         | both TE001 and GM0002 are in the compatible list
2           | false        | AW123 is not in the compatible list
3           | true         | both TK123 and GS123 are in the compatible list
```

I can't find a viable way to achieve that, I tried some combination of `JSON_OVERLAPS` and `MEMBER OF` without any success

Answer (score 0):

This is can be solved by bit a complicate query:

```
SELECT 
    machines.*,
    JSON_LENGTH(machines.cells),
    sum(data.code MEMBER OF (machines.cells))
FROM
machines,
JSON_TABLE(
   '["TE001", "GM0002", "TK123", "GS123", "LL321"]',
   "$[*]"
   COLUMNS(code varchar(32) PATH "$")
) data
GROUP BY machines.machine_id, machines.cells
HAVING JSON_LENGTH(machines.cells) = sum(data.code MEMBER OF (machines.cells))
;
```

Here a fiddle: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=012718ff7d3b9ce7275971ba83f7cc9b&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

The approach is convert JSON to table using  [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) and join it to source table.
I'm not test performance of query but it do this job :)